# How to un-make a repository folder in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I accidentally made my Desktop folder into an SVN repository. How do I reverse this? I don't want to delete the folder, but I can't figure out how to undo this.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The answer is to delete the .svn folder inside the folder you want to disconnect from SVN. You may need to enable visibility of hidden items to see this.